# R-lang: remove first character if equal to quotation mark

Tags: regex, r, gsub

R newbie. I am trying to remove the, " from the beginning and end of a line in a dataframe. I do not want to remove if the quotation is not the first or last character. I'm not sure why the following is not working on my dataframe of data, where each line is a datapoint of text.

The quotations are not due to being a character string, but are a part of the text.

a line of the dataframe looks something like this:

```
x<-  '"hello world. She said, "hello again" it was a pleasant response"'
```

result should be:

```
x2 <- 'hello world. She said, "hello again" it was a pleasant response"'
```

I thought that this would work:

```
gsub("\\n\"", "", df)
```

but, this doesn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: you need to put enclose your string `df` in single quotes (i.e. `df <- '"hello world"'`)

Comment: Your definition of `df` is not valid. Did you try to run that line? I still don't understand if the quotes are actually in the string or are just the result of the `print` method. Define correctly your string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can trim a quotation mark from the end of the string like this:

```
x <- gsub('"$','',x)
```

and from the beginning of the string like this:

```
x <- gsub('^"','',x)
```

since the characters `$` and `^` match the end and beginning of the string.  For example:

```
myData<-data.frame(foo=c('"asdf"','ASDF'),
                   bar=c('jkl;','"JKL;"'))
myData
#>     foo    bar
#>1 "asdf"   jkl;
#>2   ASDF "JKL;"

# trim the quote characters from myData$foo
myData$foo <- gsub("^\"|\"$", "", myData$foo)
myData

#>   foo    bar
#>1 asdf   jkl;
#>2 ASDF "JKL;"
```

Comment: why does gsub transform the data into a concatenated string? I have multiple rows here, and the result ends up looking like "c(\"\\\"row1\\\"\", \row2\\\"\"). How do I end up with a draframe in the original format?

Comment: Are you passing your whole data.frame as the argument `x`?  If your data.frame is called `myData` and you want to transform the field `foo`, you call `myData$foo <- gsub('^\"|\"$', "", myData$foo)`

Comment: @Jthorpe, thanks! I am calling the specific column, foo. But its concatenating all rows into each row. So row 1=c(row1, row2, so on), row 2=(row1, row2, so on). Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: can you post a reproducible example?  I added a bit of code and output for my solution which seems to work

Comment: ah, got it working from your comment example. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be `trimws` which will remove *all* `"` at the beginning or end of the string.

```
trimws(x, whitespace = '"')
#[1] "hello world. She said, \"hello again\" it was a pleasant response"
```

Or only from the beginning:

```
trimws(x, "left", '"')
#[1] "hello world. She said, \"hello again\" it was a pleasant response\""
```

Another option might be to use `startsWith` and `substring`.

```
if(startsWith(x, '"')) substring(x, 2) else x
#[1] "hello world. She said, \"hello again\" it was a pleasant response\""
```